# Restore database from dump

Tags: mysql

Restoring a database from the dump was completed without exceptions. Attempting to restart service mysql ended unsuccessfully. In the log information is not available. Can you please tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look [Error Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-log.html).

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=801607) could be your issue.  Check all the log files and the directories' permissions are properly set.